# Is it possible/legal to swap vectors of different items?

Tags: c++, templates, polymorphism, stdvector, swap

I am working on some polymorphic container that internally uses `std::vector` for storing particular items. The containers storing objects of different types (lets say `int` and `double`) may be accessed through common base class pointer.

The implementation looks like this:

```
class ContainerInterface {
public:
    virtual ~ContainerInterface() = default;
    virtual void swap(ContainerInterface& other) = 0;
    /* ... */
};

template<class C>
class Container : public ContainerInterface {
    std::vector<C> items{};
    std::type_index t_id{typeid(C)};
    /* some other stuff */
public:
    /* ... */
    void swap(ContainerInterface& other) override { /* ? */ }
};
```

One of the tasks is to be able to swap two containers accessed through this polymorphic base class, as it has everything for run-time type checking. Also it is important not to store the the `vector` object on heap (to allow swapping pointers) as the wrapping container is pretty light-weight by itself and additional de-referencing during element access is quite unwanted.

I know that basically `std::vector` object is a type of handler, which stores a pointer to data and something to determine current size and max size (like two `size_t` variables) thus any instantiation should have the same size ant layout, but that is not stated in the standard (or is it?).

I stuck at the next question:
Is it possible to swap `std::vector`s of different types? Or otherwise is it legal to just `memcpy` respective parts of wrapping container?

**Update**:
It is possible to achieve similar effect with the use of opaque type for members. I just want to simulate this using the virtual base class and the fact that `std::vector` is originally a kind of data handler.

Comment: What would it mean to swap a vector of int and a vector of double? What would you expect to happen?

Comment: I have to wrappers, each contains it's own instantiation of std::vector. I expect that entire state of the wrappers (regardless of location - stack or heap) including the parts respective to vectors' objects would swap. Because of the wrapper's polymorphism the type of managed items after the swapping could be determined correctly. I am mostly afraid of wrong memory layouts...

Comment: If you were to swap them, you'd end up with, e.g., a `vector<int>` that holds `double`s.

Comment: You can swap the elements if you don't mind all of the `double`s being damaged trying to fit them into an `int` and vice-versa. Trying to swap the underlying buffers is a bad-bad-bad idea. `int`s and `double`s won't make sense if interpreted as the other, assuming they are even the same size.

Comment: The point is that i access the vectors through the virtual functions, thus after swap the type of vector (vector<int> or vector<double>) would be dispatched correctly...

Comment: @Gleb you can't change the dynamic type of an object; your `Container<double>` and `Container<int>` will stay those types and will not swap them when you swap the contents of the object.

Comment: Or, to be clear, after the swap the virtual functions will dispatch to the same underlying implementation.

Comment: @JamesPicone you are right, I was thinking about swapping v_tables (that is undefined behavior) or the to base class (that is actually the usage of opaques). So probably it is impossible...

Comment: That particular undefined behaviour will almost certainly bite you; compilers can and will 'devirtualise' virtual functions if they can establish the dynamic type of the object. See https://godbolt.org/z/5B03u1 for example.